# Can't get my android device to be connected to my game via Unity Remote5

Tags: android, unity

Im trying to test out my game on Unity Remote5, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to work...

I enabled the needed settings in the dev settings. downloaded the android sdk and adb controller, tried having my phone on different usb settings (MTP, PTP,etc...) and still can't get it to work.

I'm using a Meizu m3 note, if anyone else has got one to work.

Comment: Do Your PC sees Device when connected? Dont You miss required driver?

Answer (score 1):

Having had many problems with the Unity Remote, I suspect you are missing the same critical requirement that I had.

As mentioned, and for the point of clarity, there are a few initial requirements you need to check to get Unity Remote working:

- You must have the respective USB drivers installed, corresponding with the manufacturer of your phone. You will often find these on the manufacturers website, and sometimes, the phone has an installer available to install the drivers when you first connect to your computer. In most cases, you should need these drivers before you can even access your phone, through file manager.
- You must have [the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) installed. If you are unsure, you can simply install Android Studio; it comes with it.
- You must have [developer mode enabled on your android device, with *at least* "USB Debugging" enabled](http://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/). You may have to enable more features for greater compatibility, or further debugging capability. If Unity Remote *did* work, and all of a sudden stops, double check that developer mode is *still* enabled. As I have found, it can turn it self off after a set period of time.

Once you have ticked these boxes, you may find that it still doesn't work. This is where I got stuck for some time - there is something else that Unity fails to tell you.

In most cases, you must have Unity Remote connected and running **before** you open Unity. That said, I find that this is an "initial" requirement. If you should accidentally close (or crash) Unity Remote during the same session, you generally do not have to close Unity again, to ensure that it opens *before* Unity.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful reply :) I'll download the usb driver and see if it will finally work